# How to build a "wallet" compatible app for UWP

Tags: c#, windows-10-universal

Microsoft's "Wallet" App for Windows 10 Mobile allows you to manage all kinds of membership cards, loyalty cards, tickets and so on in one place.

You can also install additional apps that interact with the wallet. The Lufthansa app for example can add your bording card to the wallet.

[image: The startup screen of the wallet app (in german) with an option to search the store for wallet compatible apps]
[image: search results in the store for wallet compatible apps]

(Sorry the screenshots are in German. The scrennshot on the left shows an option to search the store for wallet ("Brieftasche") compatible apps, the one on the right shows the search results)

So far for background. **Now, my problem:**

I would like to build an app that lets you add photographs or PDFs to the wallet app (I have a couple of printed notes, timetables etc. in my physical wallet and I think it would be handy to have them on hand in the wallet app).

So far, I couldn't find anything on how to mark an app as "wallet-compatible" and how to add items to the wallet programmatically.

Any experiences anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a wallet app with the [Windows.ApplicationModel.Wallet](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.applicationmodel.wallet.aspx) classes.

Use the WalletManager class to request your app's wallet store and then create WalletItems with your images, notes, etc. to add to it

See [Wallet for Windows Phone Store apps](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn631258.aspx) for an overview and sample code. The same API for Windows Phone 8.1 Store apps works for UWP apps.